# Using basename dirname to split a file path and to run the run

Tags: bash, scripting, dirname, basename

I have a generic filepath- `/home/aa/bb/cc/d.txt` and want to script something like this-

so in the script, one thing would be for it to take that `/path/to/testcase/d.txt`

And split it into

`working_dir = /path/to/testcase`

`netlist = d.txt`

then the script would do:

`cd $working_dir`

`<run $netlist>`

I want to use basename and dirname to split the filepath here. Can anyone help me with this?

Expecting to run a testcase from a particular file path but making the command line generic for everyone to use.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, but something like `"$(basename "$(dirname "$working_dir")")"`?

Comment: `"${filepath##*/}"` and `"${filepath%/*}"` could be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

We have 2 native linux commands `basename` & `dirname` which will be perfect for your requirement. These commands comes with package `coreutils`.

Here is an example:

```
$ dirname /usr/local/xyz/home/test/foo.bar
/usr/local/xyz/home/test

$ basename /usr/local/xyz/home/test/foo.bar
foo.bar
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: While those commands are provided by `coreutils` in Linux, they are defined by POSIX and available on any UNIX/Linux system